# Getting Error controller.go:96 No RenderArg names found for render call

Tags: revel

After creating a sample project or running any sample project that comes with the revel framework i get the above error, though visiting the index page of any sample displays properly i get this error on the command line where i run revel. I am using go version xgcc (Ubuntu 4.9.1-0ubuntu1) 4.9.1 linux/386. Please how do i resolve this error, i am new to go and revel development. I have already searched online for revel related solutions but dont seem to come across anyone with this particular problem.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and the go version is 1.2, not sure how to determine the revel version.

Comment: Could you share more info about your environment such as Go version, Revel version and OS version?